# Changing SearchDisplayController Delegate in interface builder

Tags: ios, ios5, delegates, interface-builder, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to show a search bar above a table with a list of recent searches that will swap to matching search results once someone enters a search term.

I want to set a custom class `MySearchViewController` to be the delegate for doing the search and managing the display of search results back to the table so that I can separate the code and not have conditional statements in the default controller.

I've found a bunch of examples that describe how to do this in code but I can't figure out how to do it using Interface Builder.

I've tried dragging a new viewcontroller into my xib and setting the custom class to `MySearchViewController` and then dragging outlets from the `SearchDisplayController` as hinted at here: http://goo.gl/RgmwG

I've also tried dragging an Object into the objects column and changing this class to `MySearchViewController`.

But I feeling completely lost and really just trying things randomly. I'm guessing that I also need to create a property/IBOutlet for the `SearchDisplayController` somewhere but again lost.

If anyone has a reference to how to go about this I'd be so happy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most problems, it seems pretty obvious in retrospect.

- Add an 'object' placeholder in interface builder (orange cube).
- Change the objects custom class to the class you want to be the delegate - e.g. `MySearchViewController`
- Remove the default outlets from the standard `SearchDisplayContoller` to connect with the `MySearchViewController` object (see screenshot)
- Make sure that the new delegate has an outlet to a parent view (in my case `View`)
- Make sure that the delegate class is initiated from somewhere

  ```
  // I did this from the parent ViewConroller, but probably better from the main app delegate?  
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MSSearchViewController *searchViewController;
  ```

Hope this helps someone else who was also stuck!

[image: Outlets for MySearchViewController]